# Insert key's value in the array of object having same key

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Say I've an array of object:

```js
const Info = [{
    "id": "1aa2",
    "details": [{
      "name": "rusty",
      "age": "12",
      "favourite": [ObjectId("602b696cb783fc15845d015e"), ObjectId("602b696cb783fc15845d0112")]
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "3aa2",
    "details": [{
      "name": "john",
      "age": "122",
      "favourite": [ObjectId("602b696cb783fc15845d0112s"), ObjectId("602b696cb783fc15845d01wqs")]
    }]
  }
]
```

I want to merge favourite in one array as:

```
["favourite": [
  ObjectId("602b696cb783fc15845d015e"), 
  ObjectId("602b696cb783fc15845d0112"), 
  ObjectId("602b696cb783fc15845d0112s"), 
  ObjectId("602b696cb783fc15845d01wqs")
  ]
]
```

I tried using for loop but it's creating nasty nested for loop which is reducing performance a lot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: What is the `ObjectId` function? What does *"I want to merge favourite in one array"* mean? Please show your nested loops solution, since that will help us understand what you're trying to do and help us point you at where the performance issues might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to iterate through Info collection, iterate through 'details' sub-collection, and copy all data into a new array. After, just create a new structure using `favs` variable content or paste this code as object value directly.

BTW your result array need's to contain an object at least, like that:

```
[ { favourite: [...] } ]
```

About nested structures, you should try https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flatMapDeep (at least just check the code)

```js
const Info = [{
    "id": "1aa2",
    "details": [{
      "name": "rusty",
      "age": "12",
      "favourite": ['ObjectId("602b696cb783fc15845d015e")', 'ObjectId("602b696cb783fc15845d0112")']
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "3aa2",
    "details": [{
      "name": "john",
      "age": "122",
      "favourite": ['ObjectId("602b696cb783fc15845d0112s")', 'ObjectId("602b696cb783fc15845d01wqs")']
    }]
  }
]

const favs = Info.reduce((acc, item) => {
    item.details.forEach(detail => {
      acc.push(...detail.favourite);
    })
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(favs);
```